# Determine the type of the date C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

1. I have a windows server LAN
2. I have multiple devices associated with it
3. Each device is different from the type of dates (AD (miladi), AH (hijri))
4. I have a problem in my project a different type dates from device to device
5. The project has publish on the server
6. Is there a way to read the date  type  from server
7. My Project C# Windows Form I am Use multiple layer in My Project And I am use datetimepicker And Datetime.now And monthcalendar## how solve this proplem ##

Comment: By "device", do you mean Windows machines running your Winforms app, who all send their data to the same server?

Comment: device is Computer User 
and iam take shortcute from my project to device user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not asking about a type of a date but about so called "culture".
A culture represents the user locale of the system and it defines a date format, a number format... You can retrieve the current culture by using [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Yeah Thank You
But how can you control the type date

Comment: What do you mean "control the type date"? Do you want to change a date format that is displayed to users?